# PHP rand query results - check so the new randomized query is not the same as previous

Tags: php, mysql, session

my PHP code looks like this right now:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE `id` = '$id' ORDER BY RAND()") or die(mysql_error());
$cmd = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

$question = $cmd['question'];
```

Right now, the questions just get randomized - which is fine - but sometimes the same question appears again, and I don't want that. I assume you can fix this with a session. But how? If someone can fix the code, I'd really appreciate.

Comment: Side-note: It's not completely random if you're intervening.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE `id` = `$id` AND `id` NOT IN (";
$query .= implode(', ', array_keys($_SESSION['questions']));
$query .= ') ORDER BY RAND()';
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// Here add the returned questions to the $_SESSION['questions'] array so they would not appear again.
```

I don't know how the rest of the program works, so the logic you need may be a little different, but I'm sure that sort of query is what you're looking for.

Comment: use array_flip and implode to make that foreach go away :)

Comment: Won't work as you have a quotes mismatch (`'string"`). Also what's with this syntax? `$k . ', ';` will do nothing with `$k`. Maybe you mean `$k .= ', ';`.

Comment: @Rikudo: Nice spot, hower $k is even re-used as an iterator variable. So all bad :).

Comment: Thanks for pointing those out, edited to create a working example!

Comment: Also, I don't see a quote mismatch there?  Perhaps I'm just being blind, though?...

Comment: @Pete171: To get a comma seperated list out of an array, use implode instead. If you need the keys, use `array_keys` first, like `$query .= implode(', ', array_keys($_SESSION['questions']));` - basically what you do with the `foreach` but sparing the need to remove the last `, ` you add at the end and you need to call `substr` for. Should make it more readable.

Comment: Never thought of doing that before, for some reason.  Thanks.  Have edited my example accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE `id` = '$id' ORDER BY RAND()") or die(mysql_error());
$question = null;
while ($cmd = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    if (array_search($cmd['question'], $_SESSION['asked']))
        continue;
    $question = $cmd['question'];
    $_SESSION['asked'][] = $question;
    break;
}
if (!$question) {
    // No unique questions found.
} else {
    // $question will be unique here
}
```

Comment: I am trying to use your example, but the same question comes again and again.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the ID of all previous asked questions inside your session:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['QuestionAsked']))
{
    $_SESSION['QuestionAsked'] = array();
}
```

You can then extend your query to exclude all asked questions:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `questions`';
if ($_SESSION['QuestionAsked'])
{
    $askedIds = implode(',', $_SESSION['QuestionAsked']);
    $query .= sprintf(' WHERE `id` NOT IN (%s)', $askedIds);
}
$query .= ' ORDER BY RAND()';
```

And finally after querying a new question, add it to the session:

```
$_SESSION['QuestionAsked'][] = $currentQuestionId;
```